# MySQL Conditional "ON" Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I have two tables: Programs and Departments.

Each program belongs to one department. The twist is, the programs table has an optional field called override_dept_id. When this field is not null, it takes precedence over the value in the department_id field.

My query needs to be able to check that if the override_dept_id field is null or not. The result of this decides which key is used on the join of the departments table. I have tried a few different ways, but I'm not doing something correctly.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT p.id, p.program, p.full_name, d.department 
FROM programs p
LEFT JOIN departments d
CASE
    WHEN p.override_dept_id IS NOT NULL THEN (ON p.override_dept_id = d.id)
    ELSE (ON p.department_id = d.id)
END
ORDER BY p.full_name ASC
```

Comment: Put ON before case statement

Comment: The syntax is [`... table1 JOIN table2 ON condition ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `on` keyword must follow the joined table - but you could move the logic to the `on` clause itself:

```
SELECT    p.id, p.program, p.full_name, d.department 
FROM      programs p
LEFT JOIN departments d ON d.id = COALESCE(p.override_dept_id,  p.department_id)
ORDER BY  p.full_name ASC
```

Comment: great. This is much neater than having to slog through a bunch of conditionals.